# performSegueWithIdentifier is being skipped *SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I have a UITableViewController that I would like people to access as the main page. I do have a login view controller but I do not want this to be my initial view controller. I have an if statement checking if the user has logged in previously. If not, I would like to perform a segue to the login view controller. When I run the app however, it goes through the if statement, recognizes that the user is == nil, and then goes right over the performSegueWithIdentifier operation.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if user == nil {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegue", sender: self)

        }
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are u using nsuserdefaults to store user credentials?

Comment: Maybe try `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegue", sender: self)
})` also make sure your shouldPerformSegue isn't returning false.

Comment: Texas = No, I am using Parse.

Comment: boidkan = It is returning true and yet still not segue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should move your code into the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` method. 
Then it should use properly.

But now the view flickers a short time. To remove that flickering, just hide the view in your `viewWillApear` method:

```
self.view.hidden = true
```

Also the `viewDidLoad` method doesn't get called everytime the view appears but only the first time it loads. If you for example perform a segue and return back to the view, it doesn't load again but only calls `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` again.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that. My annoyance is that for a quick moment, when calling viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, the main TableVC appears for a moment and then goes to the Login Screen. I would rather it just go to the Login screen if user was nil. Any way to avoid the flicker of the main VC?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Just add `self.view.hidden = true` to your `viewWillApear` method to resolve that.

Comment: I have a suspicion that I have not yet identified the issue. When I add breakpoints to my code, I see it go through the if statement, read through the perfromsegue function, and then continue down the page, as if the perfromsegue function wasn't even there. Regardless of if the method is in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad

Comment: Sorry. I was unclear. I had read about that as a possible solution, and people mentioned that it would do that. So I tried it and same issue. It goes right over the method and stays on the main VC. This TableViewController has a nav controller embedded in, which is the initial View. Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm sorry. At the moment I don't know any possible problem, that could cause your error. It's suspicious, that it runs through your code without calling the segue. Maybe the segue isn't set correctly and points to nowhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71120/discussion-between-octavio-antonio-cedeno-and-christian-woerz).

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3.0, try to run on the main thread like this.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it is hard to say.

1. Do you have a button or something with an already established segue, and have you provided the identifier for the segue? I made a similar call in viewDidLoad and it worked.
2. Have you embedded the view controller in a UINavigationController? If not, performing the segue is not possible. It sounds like you're using a UITableViewController, which inherits from UIViewController. So this may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in   
        let viewController:UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerClassId") as! ViewControllerClassName
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

this code solved my problem.
use my code instead of 
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegue", sender: self)
and give your destination ViewController an ID like ViewControllerClassId